# Significance of an eigenvector being equal to a unit vector?

Tags: matrices, soft-question, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was reading ahead in my math book when I came across a matrix denoted as A = $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0\\
2 & -2 & 0\\
6 & 0 & -2\\
\end{bmatrix}$.
I then found the eigensystem for A to be $E_{\lambda=0}=span\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
3\\
\end{bmatrix}, E_{\lambda=-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
6\\
\end{bmatrix},
E_{\lambda=-2}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\ 
1\\
\end{bmatrix}=\hat{k}.
$
Is there a significance of $\lambda$ = -2 and its corresponding eigenvector of $\hat{k}$ in relation to A? I ask out of curiosity as I love to try and understand all outcomes in math. Thanks!

Comment: The eigenvectors are not unique and, in fact, only give a direction, so you can always make an eigenvector a unit vector (i.e. something that implies a direction).

Comment: @Jared Though old (and just for context), I believe the OP refers to a unit vector as the vector given by $(\hat e_i)_j = \delta_{ij}$---not to a vector of unit norm. This is standard in a lot of introductory mathematical classes in linear algebra and/or multivariable physics.

Answer (score 2):

Given an eigenvector, any multiple of it is also an eigenvector.  You can normalize each eigenvector or not, as you wish.  So there is no significance to the magnitude of an eigenvector being $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if a unit vector is the eigenvector then the corresponding column of the matrix is proportional to that unit vector and vice versa.  So if the third column of a matrix is $[0,0,4,0]'$ then the third unit vector is also the eigenvector with eigenvalue equal to 4.

Comment: You're misusing the term "unit vector".

Comment: I indeed omitted an adjective on the term unit vector.

Comment: When I am saying "unit vector" I am relating the vector in question to the versors of the coordinate system. Given that we are in R^3, we find the versors to be equal to i*, j*, and k*, where all of these vectors are orthogonal to one another and have a magnitude of 1. This is what I meant by a "unit vector".